# Is it Islamic to execute people who insult prophets other than Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, sunni, prophets, shafii, blasphemy

I understand that insulting any prophet is kufr

> Additionally, scholars have agreed unanimously that whoever insults, disrespects or belittles any one of the prophets, may Allaah exalt their mention, will be a Kaafir (disbeliever).
>   -[Ruling on the one who insulted or belittled a Prophet - IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=53874)

However, it seems to me that Muslims react very strongly when Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) is insulted, but don't seem to care much if any other prophet is insulted.

**Is it Islamic to react more strongly to insults against Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) compared to other prophets?**

Also, I understand that if someone insults Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) the insulter can be executed (punished with death).

> The scholars are unanimously agreed that a Muslim who insults the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) becomes a kaafir and an apostate who is to be **executed**. This consensus was narrated by more than one of the scholars, such as Imaam Ishaaq ibn Raahawayh, Ibn al-Mundhir, al-Qaadi ‘Iyaad, al-Khattaabi and others. Al-Saarim al-Maslool, 2/13-16 -[Ruling on one who insults the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) - IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/22809)

**Is it Islamic to execute people who insult prophets other than Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him)?**

I understand that

> To sum up, we prefer our Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) over all the other Prophets and over all of mankind, because of the evidence that has been narrated concerning that, whilst also respecting the rights of the other Prophets and Messengers and believing in them and respecting them. 
>   - [The superiority of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) to all of creation - IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/10669)

However, I don't understand why execution, punishment and anger should only be when Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) is insulted, shouldn't we care when the other Prophets and Messengers are insulted?

Comment: +1 good question , you can answer this this related  question:http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7639/what-are-the-possible-shariah-compliant-ways-of-tackling-the-christianization

Comment: It depends on who has inherited the legacy of that prophet. For instance, though Prophet Musa (AS) is *our* prophet too, it is the Jews who "own" his legacy, while, in the case of Jesus (AS), it is the Christians who "own" it, owing to the fact that they predate this ummah. So in the moral realm they are our prophets; in terms of being religious leaders of humanity, however, their legacy belongs to the people who claim to follow them and inherit them. It reduces to a matter of chronological precedence.

Answer (score 3):

> **Iman was defined by the Holy Prophet (pbuh) as:**
>
> ■        That you affirm your faith in Allah,
>   ■        in His Angels,
>   ■        in His Books,
>   ■        in His Apostles,
>   ■        in the Day of Judgment, and
>   ■        you affirm your faith in the Divine Decree about good and evil.

**So Bases of Eemaan are six**

> > 1. Believe in Allah, Tawheed
> > 2. Believe in His Angles
> > 3. **`Believe in His Messengers`**
> > 4. Believe in His Books
> > 5. Believe in Qadar of Allah, that Allah has power over good or bad
> > 6. Believe in Judgment Day

So disrespecting/insulting or ignoring any of the prophets is considered as `Kufr`.
Execution upon insulting the Muhammad (SM.) was ruled on this `kufr`. And since disrespecting other prophets is also `kufr`, the criminal should also be punished.

EDIT:

I'll try my best to know about this from trustworthy resources.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you read the FAQ.  We would like to request that you add citations to your last part, backing up the ruling of execution with ***authentic*** sources.  We ask that you look around at the other questions and answers to get a feel how this place works.  This place isn't a forum like any other, nor is it a debate site or a fatwa site, answers are required to be backed up with citations from the Quran, authentic Sunnah, reliable/authentic fatwas from reliable scholars, and or from any other Islamic resource.

Comment: Salam to you too and Thank you for correcting me. I should not have conclude anything without authentic resource. I've updated the last sentence of my answer. I'll try to include proper citations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The punishment of insulting any prophet is the same as that of insulting the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ.

This applies to every prophet whose prophethood is established and agreed upon in Islam - such as Noah, Abraham, Isaac, Jacob, Joseph, Moses, David, Solomon, Jesus etc.

> فيمن شتم الأنبياء أو أحدا منهم أو تنقصه قتل ولم يستتب ومن سبهم من أهل الذمة قتل إلا أن يسلم
>
> Anyone who reviles one or all of the prophets or disparages any of them is killed and not asked to repent. Any dhimmi who curses them is also killed unless he becomes Muslim.
>
> <sup>— [Al-Shifaa bi Ta'reef Huqooq al-Mustafaa](https://shamela.ws/book/23645/1370)</sup>

> والحكم في سب سائر الأنبياء كالحكم في سب نبينا
>
> The judgement on insulting all other prophets is the same as the judgement on insulting our prophet
>
> <sup>— [As-Saarim al-Maslool ‘ala Shaatim ar-Rasool](https://shamela.ws/book/7344/569)</sup>

> سب سائر الأنبياء والملائكة كسب النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم بلا خلاف
>
> Insulting all other prophets and angels is like insulting the Prophet (Muhammad) ﷺ and on this there is no disagreement
>
> <sup>— [Al-Saif al-Maslool ‘ala man Sab ar-Rasool](https://shamela.ws/book/17816/327#p1)</sup>

Answer (score -3):

I'm not a scholar, or anything of the sort, but when I'd asked a woman I know (who's generally wise and knowledgeable, much more than me, concerning Islam) I told her that there was a concept I didn't understand.

She'd asked me what it was, and I'd said: "In many undeveloped 'Muslim' countries, where there are many uneducated people, when there were polls done, staggeringly high amounts of each population believed in the actual execution of people that were born into Muslim families, and then later converted to a different religion. I asked my mother about it. She said it's true, we're to kill those that convert away. Is this true? I feel like it's not right in Islam..."

The woman replied: "We're SUPPOSED to? The sense you're speaking of is the literal interpretation! The people that convert away from Islam though born into Islamic families merit death, but we're not actually supposed to kill them."

This is my view, how I understand it. It is very high sin to dare insult the prophets, any and all of them, as we love them above ourselves. But as I comprehend it, we don't take it in the literal sense of the term - they deserve death for what they've done, and we should punish them, surely, but actual execution? Is that true? If it is, I need to see the proof. Truly Allah's verses can rid me of doubt.